# fitting a sarimax model into the data using statsmodels in python3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, statsmodels

Does anyone know what are the differences between using the following commands in `statsmodels` in python for fitting a SARIMAX model?

```
statsmodels.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(data, order, .....)
statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX(data, order, ....)
statsmodels.tsa.SARIMAX(data, order, ....)
```

Comment: two of the three shouldn't work. So what's the question?

Comment: A general explanation about the dual import structure in statsmodels is here http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/importpaths.html

Comment: @user333700 all of them work!

Comment: thank you for the second comment

Comment: import statsmodels.tsa; statsmodels.tsa.SARIMAX raises an AttributeError

Comment: not on my computer!

Comment: What statsmodels version do you have installed? `statsmodels.tsa.__init__.py` is NOT supposed to have any imports and should raise the AttributeError. Only the `api.py` modules include all the imports.

Comment: statsmodels==0.8.0